# put a value inside to a TextArea in a PHP file

Tags: php, html

Could someone please let me know the mistake I have done here..

```
echo '<button onclick="document.getElementById("."formInner".").innerHTML= document.getElementById("."SaveTheForm".").innerHTML"  type="button">Edit the Table</button>';

echo '<textarea  id="formInner"></textarea>';
```

SaveTheForm is an id of a form.

Comment: Could you tell me whats wrong.?

Comment: The values inside the Form are not displaying inside the textarea. I think the problem is with "document.getElementById("."formInner".").innerHTML= document.getElementById("."SaveTheForm".").innerHTML"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this

```
echo '<form id="SaveTheForm">';
echo '<button onclick="document.getElementById(\'formInner\').innerHTML=document.getElementById(\'SaveTheForm\').innerHTML"  type="button">Edit the Table</button>';

echo '<textarea  id="formInner"></textarea>';
echo '</form>';
```

Thanks

Comment: :) I should thank you. It's working. why do we need to use \'A\' ? It varies time to time. And it confuse me always. What is the effect on using \'\' instead of just only using double quotations?

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="document.getElementById(\'formInner\').innerHTML= document.getElementById(\'SaveTheForm\').innerHTML"
```

sry changed. u need to escape the quotes

Comment: But after that it gives me an error like TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.

Comment: Npe still it gives me an error like SyntaxError: illegal character.

Answer (score 0):

check your javascript code,

```
document.getElementById("."formInner".")
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('formInner') // no dots
```

btw: everytime is better have javascript separate in .js files

Comment: hi thanks for commenting. But my problem is, I'm writing it inside an echo tag. So they consider it as an error. But I will try using a seperate js file.

Comment: you should escape it
`echo('document.getElementById(\'formInner\')');`